# What is the best argumented proof of the statement "IE6 is not standards compliant"?

Tags: internet-explorer-6, web-standards, w3c-validation

I've met a new friend. That's a woman and she is a designer. And she has a strange attitude towards IE of version 6 (and older). She just **LOVES** it. And she has a strong argument: "when I started programming websites, there were no "correct" browsers", so she beleives, that IE is the most correct ever. I'm a programmer and I was always scared by designing something, but I am not new to CSS, HTML and Javascript. However, professionally, I just lack serious proofs, that IE actually never tried to follow any standards.

And now I have problems trying to prove my position. From a lot of professional literature I read in my life I heard, that IE really violated standards seriously both in HTML, CSS and JavaScript. But I can't find valuable of this fact. Can you help in this quest? :)

Comment: Is this like the reddit thing about how do you know someone has an --insert desireable entity here... - They tell you. I think the term she is fairly well entrenched for the female gender don't you think? lol

Comment: I think it may be pointless to put a lot of effort into convincing her. It seems to me one must ignore an awful lot to think that IE6 is the most 'correct' browser when it comes to standards compliance. I suspect what happened is that she always designed for IE6 solely, and so problems with her designs in other browsers were, in her mind, always the fault of those other browsers.

Comment: Oh and btw this is why I don't date programmers :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With all due respect, you're both probably wrong.

First off, it's probably not subjective or controversial to say that IE6 is horrible.

But, *at the time it was released almost ten years ago*, AFAIK IE6 was one of the most standards-compliant browsers out there, in terms of CSS compliance.  The problem is that the standard evolved significantly since those draft revisions ten years ago, and there hasn't been the push to auto-update the browser like Firefox and Chrome have.  That has left a significant installed base of IE6 around.

She probably loves the browser because she's let her skills lapse in terms of CSS.

Comment: Agreed. Bashing IE6 for not complying with standards that were published after IE7 was released is a bit silly.

Comment: But we can definitely bash Microsoft for not aggressively updating it and setting the WWW's development back at least 5-8 years...

Answer (score 5):

Saying "it was good when i started" is *not* a strong argument. She reminds me of a point that Crockford made in his talks, that the main opponents to technology, the ones that were the most prone to oppose change was us, the power users... "I never use this feature, but still get things done therefore this feature is crap" is a common bias, even when you know about it and look out for it...

IE6 was the very best at a time. Not anymore. Things change... As pointed, the ACID test, the user experience and most of all the non-implementation of all the standards that could help us advance are all valid reasons for axing IE6

---

But anyway, is it important that your lady friend likes IE6? Do you feel strongly about it? Perhaps you should let her like what she wants and not think too much about it :)

Comment: +1 for Crockford, I thought of that whilst I was reading the question too.

Comment: "is it important that your lady friend likes IE6?"

Surely, no. Just it take it professional, not personal. It's just an argument of two friends. Nothing more.

Comment: @Fractalizer: what i meant by that is that when i first read the question, i understood "she loves IE6" as she "she uses and promotes the use of IE6". That's why i added the second part, when i understood; she can love an outdated technology, and defend its use at the corresponding period. But by **today** standards, IE6 doesn't deliver anymore, as seems to be the consensus

Answer (score 1):

Well, ACID is a test page testing browsers if they follow certain web standards.
For further reading have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid2 .

Internet Explorer has and will ever ( ;-) ) display web pages differently from other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest her to try [CSS Zen Garden's "Gemination"](http://www.csszengarden.com/?cssfile=062/062.css) both on IE6 and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Run the [acid test](http://acid3.acidtests.org/), it is the best proof. Here you have a whole browser comparison test: http://www.pcgameshardware.com/aid,687738/Big-browser-comparison-test-Internet-Explorer-vs-Firefox-Opera-Safari-and-Chrome-Update-Firefox-35-Final/Practice/

Comment: ACID is good, but that link is slightly offtopic since it describes only performance differences which are not the subject of our argument.

Comment: @FractalizeR: I posted it for the acid test comparison table in the end. But yeah, most of the page is off topic.

Comment: @FractalizeR  How is it that ACID test "describes only performance differences" ?   I believe ACID was "designed to produce a clear indication of a browser's compliance to web standards"  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid1

Comment: @unhillbilly No, under "that link" I meant the link to pcgameshardware.com, where mostly only performance comparisons are listed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that IE6 is still the standard browser for a lot of users.  If a design is created on IE6 **without pushing the limits** much, then it is lickly to look OK on all broswers.

So as a tool for a web designer, IE6 may be the best browser.  (Just don't ask me to use it on my personal PC!)